# Probability of a fair die with $10$ faces

Tags: probability

A special fair die having $10$ faces numbered $1,2,...,10$ is constructed. Let $r_i$ be the result of the $i$th throw and $a$ the imaginary fifth root of unity. The question is to find out the probability of $$\sum_{i=1}^5 a^{r_i}=0$$

---

For $\sum_{i=1}^5 a^{r_i}=0$ we have that the five results should be consecutive numbers. There are $10$ ways to choose five consecutive outcomes and it can be arranged in $5!$ ways. So the probability in my view should have been $$10\cdot5!\cdot\left(\frac1{10}\right)^5$$ But this is not the correct answer. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for this not being in a comment, I don't have the reputation required; but I am wondering about the claim "There are 10 ways to choose five consecutive outcomes". Are there not only 6 possibilities for this, those being: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ $2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ $3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ $4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ $6, 7, 8, 9, 10$ Or perhaps I have misunderstood? **edit** - I understand now that you meant cyclically consecutive of course!! but I believe you have an answer in the comments now...

Comment: The numbers need not be consecutive.  $a^2=a^7$ so $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is the same as $\{1,7,3,4,5\}$ (for example).

Comment: Your idea is still good though.  by "consecutive" you should mean "contains exactly one representative from each of  $(1,6), (2,7), (3,8), (4, 9), (5,10)$"

Comment: @lulu my idea was wrong.it is not simply the case of outcomes being cyclic consecutive

Comment: Yes, but you can adapt your idea.  Just replace "consecutive" with "contains one of each remainder $\pmod 5$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking idea from the comment by @lulu we must have our outcomes coming one from each of $(1,6);(2,7);(3,8);(4,9);(5,10)$.So each outcome has two choices and we can arrange those choices in $5!$ ways.Total there are $2^5\cdot 5^5 $ ways to choose outcomes(Since each outcome can have any element from any of the five brackets above)

Hence the requisite probability is $$\frac{2^5\cdot 5!}{2^5\cdot 5^5}$$ which is $24/625$

Comment: @lulu please have a look at my solution

Comment: The total number of outcomes can instead be counted as the number of possible die roll sequences, $10^5$.